# My application runs perfectly if I apply breakpoints and run the application in debugging mode otherwise not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Ionic Framework to develop my application and I have Firebase as the back-end. I put breakpoints and try to run the application it works fine . However if I run the application without the debugger, I see values not being changed in the Firebase database and also page transition fails. Any probable reason why it behaves in this fashion.

Part of my html:

```
<a class="button button-balanced  button-block" id="snooker-button1" ng-click = "setTitle('Table 1')"  ui-sref="tableX">Table 1</a>
    <a class="button button-balanced  button-block" id="snooker-button2" ng-click = "setTitle('Table 2')" ui-sref="tableX">Table 2</a>
    <a class="button button-balanced  button-block" id="snooker-button3" ng-click = "setTitle('Table 3')" ui-sref="tableX">Table 3</a>
    <a class="button button-balanced  button-block" id="snooker-button4" ng-click = "setTitle('Table 4')" ui-sref="tableX">Table 4</a>
    <a class="button button-assertive  button-block" id="snooker-button5" ng-click = "setTitle('Table 5')" ui-sref="tableX">Table 5</a>
    <a class="button button-balanced  button-block" id="snooker-button6" ng-click = "setTitle('Table 6')" ui-sref="tableX">Table 6</a>
    <!-- <div style="" class="button-bar"></div> -->
    <div style="" class="button-bar">
       <button class="button button-calm  button-block button-outline" style="font-weight:600;" id="page3-button11" ng-click = "gameEngine_v()" >Start</button>
       <button class="button button-calm  button-block button-outline" style="font-weight:600;" id="page3-button12"ng-click = "gameEngine_v_stp()" >Stop</button>
```

Part of my Controller.js file

```
 $scope.setTitle  = function(table_title)
 {
     // table_title = "Table 1 is the title";
     table_title_g = table_title ;
     var table_db_ref_copy = new Firebase("https://glaring-torch-3069.firebaseio.com/tables/"); //database ref for the table
     var str_table_db_ref_copy = "https://glaring-torch-3069.firebaseio.com/tables/";
     var table_number = table_title_g.charAt(6);
     var str_table  = "table";
     var str_table_final = str_table.concat(table_number);// try str_table = str_table.concat(table_number)
     var str_players = "/players";
     var str_table_db_ref_players  = str_table_db_ref_copy.concat(str_table_final);
     var str_table_db_ref_players_fb = new Firebase(str_table_db_ref_players);
     var players_at_table_snapshot = null;
     var get_players_at_table =
          function(players_at_table_snapshot_actual)
          {
            players_at_table_snapshot = null;
            players_at_table_snapshot = players_at_table_snapshot_actual;
          };
    str_table_db_ref_players_fb.on('value',get_players_at_table);
    str_table_db_ref_players_fb.off('value',get_players_at_table);
    var players_at_table_data  = players_at_table_snapshot.val();
    player_one_v = players_at_table_data.players.player1;
    player_two_v  = players_at_table_data.players.player2;
    player_three_v = players_at_table_data.players.player3;
    player_four_v = players_at_table_data.players.player4;
 };
 var temp_ind = 0;
 var intvId = 0;
 $scope.gameEngine_v = function()
 {

  //  if(temp_ind == 1)
  //  {
      // intvId = setInterval(gameEngine, 3000);
        intvId = setTimeout(gameEngine, 3000);

      // gameEngine(temp_ind);
  //  }
  //  if(temp_ind == 0)
  //  {
  //    clearInterval(intvId);
  //  }

 };

 $scope.gameEngine_v_stp = function()
 {
  //  clearInterval(intvId);
   clearTimeout(intvId);
  //  gameEngine(temp_ind);
 };

 //tables_snapshot https://glaring-torch-3069.firebaseio.com/tables
 var gameEngine  = function(){
  //  if(game_s_var == 1){
         var table_db_ref = new Firebase("https://glaring-torch-3069.firebaseio.com/tables/"); //database ref for the table
         players_db_ref = new Firebase("https://glaring-torch-3069.firebaseio.com/players/"); //database ref for the list of potential players
         str_players_db_ref = "https://glaring-torch-3069.firebaseio.com/players/";

         // Basic usage of .once() to read the data located at firebaseRef.
         counter  = 0;
        var tables_snapshot = null;
        var players_snapshot = null;
        var get_tables_snapshot =
          function(datasnapshot_tables)
          {
            tables_snapshot = null;
            tables_snapshot = datasnapshot_tables;
          };

          var get_players_snapshot =
            function(datasnapshot_players)
            {
              players_snapshot = null;
              players_snapshot = datasnapshot_players;
            };
            var msg = null;
            var onComplete = function(error) {
              msg  = null;
                if (error) {
                  msg = "Failed Synchronization";
                } else {
                  msg  = "Success";
                }
              };

        table_db_ref.on('value',get_tables_snapshot);
        table_db_ref.off('value',get_tables_snapshot);
        tables_snapshot.forEach(
          function(childSnapShot)
          {
          var key = childSnapShot.key();
          var data = childSnapShot.val();
          var str_1  = "https://glaring-torch-3069.firebaseio.com/tables/";
          var str_2 = "/players";
          var str_3 =  str_1.concat(key,str_2);
          var t_mode = data.mode;
          var players = new Firebase(str_3);//path for players at the table
          players_db_ref.on('value',get_players_snapshot);
          players_db_ref.off('value',get_players_snapshot);
          var count  = 0;
          var flag = 0;
          if(t_mode == 'singles' && flag == 0)
          {
              players_snapshot.forEach(
              function(player_snaphot)
              {
                count = count + 1;
                var player_data = player_snaphot.val();
                var player_key = player_snaphot.key();
                var str_currentPlayer = str_players_db_ref.concat(player_key);//holds the url of the current player
                var currentPlayer_ref = new Firebase(str_currentPlayer);
                var player_emp_id  = player_data.emp_id;
                if(count == 1)
                {
                  players.update(
                    {
                      player1:player_emp_id
                    }
                  );
                  currentPlayer_ref.remove(onComplete);
                  var str_test = 'i am here !!';
                }
                else if (count == 2)
                {
                  players.update(
                    {
                      player2:player_emp_id
                    }
                  );
                  currentPlayer_ref.remove(onComplete);
                }
                else
                {
                  flag  = 1;
                  // return true; // to go out of forEach loop
                }
              }
            );
            //  var d =  setTimeout(gameEngine(1), 3000);

          }
          count = 0 ;

          if(t_mode == 'doubles' && flag == 0)
          {
            players_snapshot.forEach(
              function(player_snaphot)
              {
                count = count + 1;
                var player_data = player_snaphot.val();
                var player_key = player_snaphot.key();
                var player_emp_id  = player_data.emp_id;
                if(count == 1)
                {
                  players.update({ player1:player_emp_id });
                  currentPlayer_ref.remove(onComplete);
                }
                else if (count == 2)
                {
                  players.update({ player2:player_emp_id });
                  currentPlayer_ref.remove(onComplete);
                }
                else if (count == 3)
                {
                  players.update({ player3:player_emp_id });
                  currentPlayer_ref.remove(onComplete);
                }
                else if (count == 4)
                {
                  players.update({ player4:player_emp_id });
                  currentPlayer_ref.remove(onComplete);
                }
                else
                {
                  flag  = 1; // to go out of forEach loop
                }
              }
            );
          }// end of 'doubles' mode elseif
        }
      );

    // }
};
//  var d =  setTimeout(gameEngine(1), 3000);
```

})

Comment: "Any probable reason why it behaves in this fashion." Race conditions. They're a little less common in Javascript than languages with threads, but when you pause execution, the sequence of callbacks could change.

Comment: thanks @DavidEhrmann , I will go through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David has already commented this typically happens due to race conditions. In case of your JS though its because of Async calls are not handled properly. Firebase `dbref.on` is Async call. When data is received from server then the function will execute. So the processing of `tables_snapshot` & `players_at_table_snapshot` has to be inside the respective Async handler functions. You have put it outside that is causing the problems.